# Sending Push using node-apn always returns Invalid token (8)

Tags: ios, node.js, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to get my node.js app to successfully send a push notification to my device. In the beginning I was sure I'm making some mistake with my push certificate / key, so I wrote the same thing in Ruby just to be sure, in which it works perfectly.

When i try using nomad-cli (command line tool) or just use Nomad in Ruby it works fine and it takes a single PEM file that contains both key and cert

it looks like this

`apn push "21329bc4164a56226a982f3daea4e3ace5e6c1788e4dc3a75248eca330b280a300" -c ./apns.pem -m "CLI Hello"`

And returns "1 push notification sent successfully" which immediately shows it on my device.

On my node.js code, I'm using node-apn which requires separate cert and key PEM files. So I tried separating with various methods, but I always get the same error :

invalid token (8)

Which makes no sense , since the same token works with the same PEM file in the Ruby test I wrote ...

I'm really pulling my non-existing bald-headed hairs here... Stuck on this for two days now.

I tried separating with the following methods :

- Tried to just convert the p12 to pem and use the PEM for both cert/key fields
- Convert to PEM , then manually open the PEM and separate it to key.pem and cert.pem (Using `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
- Tried to split separately using the following commands: 

  `openssl pkcs12 -in apns.p12 -nocerts -out key.key // Extract key
  openssl rsa -in key.key -outform PEM -out key.pem // Decrypt key
  openssl pkcs12 -in apns.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem // Extract Certificate`

With all of these methods, my node.js code fails with an error code of 8.
My node.js code looks as follows:

```js
let apn         = require('apn')
let conn        = new apn.connection({cert: "_private/certs/dev/cert.pem", key: "_private/certs/dev/key.pem", production: false})

let note        = new apn.notification()
note.expiry     = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1 hour from now.
note.badge      = 3;
note.sound      = "ping.aiff";
note.alert      = "\uD83D\uDCE7 \u2709 You have a new message";
note.payload    = {'messageFrom': 'Caroline'};

conn.pushNotification(note, new apn.Device("21329bc4164a56226a982f3daea4e3ace5e6c1788e4dc3a75248eca330b280a300"))

conn.on('error', error => {
    console.log("ERROR" + error)
})

conn.on('transmitted', (notification, device) => {
    console.log("TRANS")
    console.log(notification)
    console.log(device)
})

conn.on('completed', () => {
    console.log("COMPLETED")
})

conn.on('transmissionError', (errorCode, notification, device) => {
    console.log("TRANS ERR")
    console.log(notification)
    console.log(device)
    console.log(errorCode)
})
```

I'm really pulling my bald-head-hairs hair. Hope someone can help :) 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
conn.pushNotification(note, new apn.Device("<21329bc4 164a5622 6a982f3d aea4e3ac e5e6c178 8e4dc3a7 5248eca3 30b280a300>"))
```

the format of the token is something like this